# Creating a SQL Server view designer like control

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I am in need of a view like designer for Winforms, so really I just need to make a control, but I'm not sure what path to go down or whether or not it has already been done.

I need something like this:

[image]

How do you think I should go about it?

Do you think that this is done in some kind of canvas? Or is there actually something that does this? I only need one with two lists that I can use multiple times. Suggestions?

**EDIT**

Its not a query designer that I want, but simply the mapping of one key to another.

Comment: I strongly suggest WPF instead of winforms (for absolutely everything) and mostly for things like this. See [my example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16087767/643085) of a similar requirement done in less than 1 hour in WPF. You could integrate that into an existing winforms application if needed, by using the `ElementHost`.

Comment: Why is it you suggest WPF? The application I have built doesn't require too much UI.

Comment: go ahead and try to implement that (with scrolling and all) in winforms. Then compare your 5000 lines of horrible GDI code with my 20 beautiful lines of XAML + 15 lines of C#. Then ask yourself that question again.

Comment: Looks like UserControl with a couple of CheckListBoxes, Labels and a single owner-drawn panel to draw relations. At first look, the task is trivial.

Comment: @Dennis I'd like to see a winforms example of that, including the drag functionality, since it looks like a trivial task for you, maybe there's something I'm missing. By the way, don't forget resolution independence and auto-sizing / auto-scaling.

Comment: @Dennis and no flicker, please.

Comment: I could do exactly what you have done in winforms in minimal lines, however I want like what I have above.

Comment: @HighCore: what was that, hmm? First of all, my comment was for OP, it is not against your opinion. The second, OP said nothing about requirements you expect from the component. Let's do not think for him. The third, I'd like to look at your 20 XAML+15 C# lines. I think, you're very hurry with your conclusions.

Comment: His UI doesn't match what I need.

Comment: @SmartLemon I didn't say "it matches", I clearly said above "see my example of a SIMILAR requirement". You could change the `Line` to a `PolyLine` and add more points and achieve this. Also, you can add a custom shape in the `DataTemplate` to achieve the diamond in the center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one by Bernardo Castilho, the CTO of componentone:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43171/A-Visual-SQL-Query-Designer

Comment: -1. There's nothing in that post that resembles what the OP requested. And by the way an answer with just a link is not really helpful.

Comment: @HighCore chill out. The OP asked `I am in need of a view like designer for winforms` - then edited his question to clarify my answer wasn't suited. `@Dennis I'd like to see a winforms example of that, including the drag functionality` - did you even bother to see the link!