# Draw shapes between listViewItems WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, highlighting

I have to simulate a communications between different elemnts in a network.

This network is represented by a listView, and each element is an Item in this listView.

The communication between these Elements must be represented by arrows, in order to have the sens of the communication.

Here is an example in the following image:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea of how to do this ?

Comment: You might want to see [my example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16087767/643085) of a similar thing, but involving 2 `DataGrid`s.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/240eb3bd-14db-4865-aaba-9a8cfd30f428/absolute-screen-coordinate-of-a-data-bound-list-box-item 
this shows you how to get the actual positions of the listboxitem's 
I would suggest creating an adorner which renders between these positions .

Answer (score 0):

first of all, since a listview or a gridview has its on ItemContainers it won't let you put elements outside the bounds of the containers. You need to inherit from an existing control (ListView), give it a Canvas panel (so you can draw wethever you want) and write the logic required to draw each ítem with the arrows.

Comment: I don't think that the user *needs* to inherit from a `ListView` as you say... that might be one option, but it's certainly not the only one. What about the `Adorner` layer?

Comment: If you use the default GridView and the ListView everything outside the Container will be cutted off.